# AutoResetEvent not working

Tags: c#, autoresetevent

My code is as shown below:

```
 static AutoResetEvent wait_till_finish = new AutoResetEvent(false);

...if (File.Exists("try.exe"))
                {
                    Thread quartus_thread = new Thread(() => qar_function(@"\quartus");
                    quartus_thread.Start();
                    wait_till_finish.WaitOne();
    // ONLY after command mode action was finished, and AutoResetEvent is set, lookfor some file in folder
                    if (File.Exists("def")) {//do something}
                }
```

And later on:

```
public void qar_function(string abc)
    { //does something...
            ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/k " + String.Join(" ", args));
            procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            procStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
            Process proc = new Process();
            proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
            proc.Start();
          // ***** now set AutoResetEvent:
            wait_till_finish.set();
```

My problem is as follows:

I have `wait_till_finish.WaitOne()' in one method, and it's in wait state AFTER I'm calling the Qar_Function method, so first I want to call the method, then I want to wait till the method is executed and finished, and then, inside the qar_function method, I set the AutoReset.

It is not working.

I'm using the debugger, and it is not waiting at the WaitOne, it's just keep moving to the next line.

What am I doing wrong?
Thx.

Comment: Did you mean to start a process or wait for that process to finish? You might want to call `proc.WaitForExit()` before setting the handle

Comment: I meant to finish my process, then back to find the file. I understnad now that it will happen when it starts, not when it finishes... How do I change that?

Comment: You have to call Reset() method somewhere in the beginning of your code, OR , initialize your AutoResetEvent with true: wait_till_finish = new AutoResetEvent(true);

Comment: @CodeInNet Why would he need to set initial state as signaled? Also you don't need to call `Reset` for `AutoResetEvent`. As the name implies, it automatically resets itself.

Comment: Doesn't work. If I set it to false, it's just keep moving on to next line and check file existance without firing the qar_function (checked in task manager-it didn't started). If set to true, it stuck without firing the qar_function.

Comment: You want to wait till the process you started finishes?

Comment: Exactly. Wait till it's finishes --> then check for file existance.

Comment: If you put `Debug.WriteLine()` calls before and after `wait_till_finish.WaitOne();` and before and after `wait_till_finish.set();` do they come out as expected? And do you perhaps need to call `Process.WaitForInputIdle()` before `wait_till_finish.set();`? Or if you want to wait for the process to exit, you must call `Process.WaitForExit()`.

Comment: Wait... why are you starting a new thread just to wait on it immediately after?

Comment: @ Luaan, I wanted to use the AutoResetEvent, that is why I've used threads (is that ok?). Secondly, I will definately try the 'waitForInputIdle()', but what is weird is that the AutoResetEvent is not working as expected. @ Matthew Watson, I've tried using the debug breakpoints, same result, it gets stuck. Never gets to the qar_function.

Comment: "Never gets to the qar_function" - This is different behaviour to what you describe in your question!

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways to wait for the process exit. One is synchronous and another is asynchronous.

If you prefer synchronous use [Process.WaitForExit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb4aw7b8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) otherwise use [Process.Exited](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.exited%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event.

So after you call `process.Start` you can call `process.WaitForExit` to wait for it to complete.

Also for me it looks like you're simply creating new thread and starting the process and planning to wait for it -- at the same time another thread is waiting for this thread. All this looks inefficient use of resources. You can avoid creating new thread and just inline the process creation and waiting for it in the calling thread itself. In that case you don't even need `AutoResetEvent`.

At that point your code becomes:

```
if (File.Exists("try.exe"))
{
    ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/k " + String.Join(" ", args));
    procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    procStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
    Process proc = new Process();
    proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
    proc.Start();
    proc.WaitForExit();

    //At this point the process you started is done.
    if (File.Exists("def")) 
    {
       //do something
    }
}
```

Comment: And of course, a `Process` is a wait handle, so you can use something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13741694/construct-task-from-waithandle-wait to get a `Task` out of it.

Comment: @Luaan Yep, Getting a `Task` out of it sounds like a good idea but the linked answer is reinventing the wheel using `ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject` which we can easily get just by subscribing the `Exited` event along with `TaskCompletionSource`.

Comment: Yeah, that's another option. I personally try to avoid events when they're unnecessary (and the `Exited` event uses the same wait handle anyway).